# Viewing auth_user model in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-registration

How do I view the contents of the auth_user model in Django?

For example, I have created a model Class called EmailList within my app. And to view the email QuerySet I can do:

```
>>> from app.models import EmailList
>>> EmailList.objects.all()
```

How would I do this same thing with the `auth_user` model, so I can view the users' emails, names, etc.? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
User.objects.all()
```